# How is atrophied muscle different than normal muscle in a chemical or biological way?

Tags: human-biology, physiology, muscles

I am a writer with a question for a story I'm working on. In it, the character suffers from muscle atrophy due to spinal damage. So that I can portray this accurately, what would cause this type of wasting? I'm hoping there is a chemical or biological difference between atrophied and regular muscle.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will be a very broad question related to the cause of the atrophy. Causes include (But by no means are nowhere limited to) - Disuse, neuropathy, injury, guillan-barre, polio, osteoarthritis, rheumatoid arthritis, burns, ALS, alcohol and so on. Each of these will have different effects. Is there a way to narrow this down, or is this a general article on regular tissue versus affected tissue?

Comment: I am writing a fiction piece. The character has spinal damage and the muscles are atrophying due to paralysis.

Comment: I edited your question to reflect this, if you think this completely changes the question you want to ask, notify me and I can roll it back. Although, either way this may belong more on biology.se.